# Choose better SQL server query plan in order to reduce server I/O and RAM usage

Tags: sql, sql-server

For my SQL server database, I have written two SQL scripts to get same output. Both are showing considerably different plans. I don't understand which one I should use.

Can someone take a look into attached SQL Plan images (Plan1 and Plan2) and help me choose the right one? My requirement is to reduce server I/O and RAM usage by these processes.

[image: Plan1]

[image: Plan2]

Here is the SQL query:

For Plan1:

```
DECLARE @SellerLocationId INT = 5
SELECT (CASE WHEN LOWER(mfn_listing_exists) = 'yes' THEN IsInStock ELSE (CASE WHEN (afn_fulfillable_quantity > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END) AS IsInStock
FROM ( select
sku,mfn_listing_exists,mfn_fulfillable_quantity,afn_fulfillable_quantity
 from rptFBA_ManageInventoryResponse
 where SellerLocationId = @SellerLocationId AND LOWER(condition) not in ('unknown','')
 )tvp
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductAmz p ON p.SKU = tvp.SKU AND p.SellerLocationId = @SellerLocationId
 where p.SKU = tvp.SKU AND p.SellerLocationId = @SellerLocationId
```

For Plan2:

```
DECLARE @SellerLocationId INT = 5
SELECT (CASE WHEN (afn_fulfillable_quantity > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsInStock
FROM ( select
sku,mfn_listing_exists,mfn_fulfillable_quantity,afn_fulfillable_quantity
 from rptFBA_ManageInventoryResponse
 where SellerLocationId = @SellerLocationId AND LOWER(condition) not in ('unknown','') AND LOWER(mfn_listing_exists) = 'yes'
 )tvp
 LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductAmz p ON p.SKU = tvp.SKU AND p.SellerLocationId = @SellerLocationId
 where p.SKU = tvp.SKU
 AND p.SellerLocationId = @SellerLocationId
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think 2nd one is better as in the first plan key lookup having 25% cost and key lookup is slower than index scan and it is slower than index seek. so instead of depending upon Key lookup lets depend upon index scan. and analyze the indexes available for that table `rptFBA_ManageInventoryResponse` and check for possibilities to create an index for faster performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for valuable response.I'll try by creating indexes on that table.